# jQuery Mobile reload current page (F5) [Single Page App]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

First of all, sorry about my English :)
I'm trying to learn jQuery Mobile and I have a question. I built an easy examples of two following pages.

**First example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile- 1.4.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/app.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js">   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
         <div role="main" class="ui-content">
             <ul data-role="listview">
                 <li><a href="views/hello.html" ><h3>Hello Stack Overflow!</h3></a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second example:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="hello">
     <div role="main" class="ui-content">
         <h3>I'm a begginer:), but...</h3>
         <div id="test">:(</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And finally i have an app.js that contains a dynamic manipulation of the Dom

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", '#hello',  function( event ) {
    $("#test").html("Let's Rock with jQuery Mobile");
});
```

Everything is fine, but when I reload `hello.html` in the browser, I lose script and framework and I receive nothing.
I am trying to find what is causing this problem, but the only solution I can find is to use multipage technique and `#` to prevent this problem.
Very often, I see few examples that does that and they reload main Dom from the start.
So if I want to reload current "hello.html" page without losing dynamic content, what should I use? Maybe use `store.js` for store current var status for javascript recall?

I am a bit confused. Any advice?

Comment: if you're using _single page model_ load libraries in head of each HTML file. If you refresh, you need to re-append all dynamic elements.